# A question about adjoint matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T:V \to V $ be a linear map on complex vector space $V$ which is equipped with complex inner product $ <. , .> $

we know there exists a unique linear operator  $T^* : V \to V $ such that $<Tx,y>=<x,T^*y>$ ( by rise representation theorem ). Now if we fix a basis for $V$ and write matrix representation of then we see that their relation are conjugate transpose. In the other hand we know that every complex inner product is determined by a Hermitian matrix in this way $$ <x,y>=x^tMy$$

now I want to show directly with matrix computations that $$(Tx)^tMy=x^tM(T^*y)$$

but I am able to proof it only in the case that $M=I$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "directly with matrix computations". Do you mean that you don't accept $$(Tx)^tMy=\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,T^*y\rangle=x^tM(T^*y)$$

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson : yes i do not accept this

Comment: OK; so, what do you mean by "directly with matrix computations"? What *would* you accept?

Comment: With out using the fact that $<Tx,y>=<x,T^*y>$

Comment: I could not go beyond this : $x^t M (T^* y)= x^t M^t (T^* y) = x^t (TM)^t y = TMxy$ Also, I'm not sure of the last step : Does $(Ax)^t=x^t A^t $ ?